# Glide & OkHttp for Android API 16 not working

Tags: android, okhttp, android-glide

I am developing Android App for API level 16 & above:

```
minSdkVersion 16, targetSdkVersion 29

compileOptions {

    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0"
annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.11.0"
```

I am using **Glide** & as per this [requirement](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/#requirements) it should work for (API level 14) or higher. **OkHttp exception** [“Expected Android API level 21+ but was 29”](https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/#version-3147) is also fixed in 3.14.7. When I compile app it crashes with following **Logcat**:

```xml
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:263)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:229)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:202)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.build(Retrofit.java:614)
        at com.example.retrofitgliderecycler.MoviesRepository.getInstance(MoviesRepository.java:33)
        at com.example.retrofitgliderecycler.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: okhttp3/internal/platform/Android10Platform
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.findPlatform(Platform.java:202)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:79)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:263) 
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:229) 
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:202) 
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.build(Retrofit.java:614) 
        at com.example.retrofitgliderecycler.MoviesRepository.getInstance(MoviesRepository.java:33) 
        at com.example.retrofitgliderecycler.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It works if I change minSdkVersion to 29.

Comment: can you post code?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna open an issue on [`okHttp`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues) as you're getting `Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: okhttp3/internal/platform/Android10Platform` which seems to be the package fault, there is the same issue [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/5826)

Comment: As per https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5-818bb78d07ce  I should use OkHttp 3.12: "Today we’re releasing OkHttp 3.13. With this update we’re bumping the project’s requirements from this:  
Android 2.3+ / API 9+ (released December 2010)  
Java 7+ (released July 2011)  
to this:  
Android 5.0+ / API 21+ (released November 2014)  
Java 8+ (released March 2014)"    I tried OkHttp 3.12 but still same issues.

Comment: You might consider downgrading to Glide 3.x alongside with OkHttp 3.x